# Down-clock 1600Mhz RAM on Macbook Pro Mid 2009

Tags: memory, upgrade

My Mac (**Mid 2009- MacBookPro5,5**) installing OS **10.8.2**.

Currently, it is using **2 x 1GB (1066 Mhz)**.

My friend gave me **2 x 2GB (1600 Mhz)** of his 2012 Mac.

**After installing 2 x 2GB (1600 Mhz)** on my Mac, it can <strike>not boot</strike> but can not start OS. This is the error that show on <strike>boot</strike> start up screen:

[image]

But it is **possible** to install **1x 1GB (1066) + 1x 2GB (1600)**. The system can **down-clock** it to **both 1066 Mhz**. But what i still have 1 x 1GB (1066) + 1x 2GB (1600) **left**!

[image: 3GB @ 1066 Mhz]

**My question is:** Any **better** solution than using 1x 1GB (1066) + 1x 2GB (1600)? 
**More certainly, is there any way to install 2 x 1600 Mhz? (even down-clocking to 1066 is accepted).**

Edit 1: 4 RAM are healthy.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the model you have supports more then 3GB of system memory? Are you 100% the memory your trying to use is not actually defective? Are you 100% was is likely the 32-bit OS X kernel can support more then 3GB?  I am going to take a very educated guess based on 15 years of solving problems like this, the problem simply is, your motherboard does not support a 2GBx2 configuration( not much you can do about that fact ).

Comment: @Ramhound No, that Macbook Pro model should definitely support 2Gbx2.

Comment: @BachT Try booting off of each of the 2 RAM modules your friend gave you separately, and if they both boot sucessfully, try running a memory check on them with Apple Hardware Test on your OS CD. I'm betting one of them has an error.

Comment: @MarcusChan: all of them are healthy. I removed each of them and plug it with a 1-GB-1066 Mhz and it work well. But both of 1600 can not start my system.

Comment: @BachT - Of course both of them being at 1600 won't boot your system.  You will have to set the frequency youself ( if the BIOS allows you to do that ) or use the correct memory frequency.  The reason a single stick works is because of the nature of DDR3 memory.

Comment: @BachT - Exact same issue: Macbook 6,1 1066 (2x1GB) ...I tried to replace with 2x4GB 1600 Crucial RAM ...won't boot..but 1x1GB (1066) + 1x4GB (1600) work shows up 5Gb (1066)...were you able to fix? thanks!

Comment: @Vikram No, my current solution is use 1x1GB (1066) + 1x2GB(1600) as your 5GB solution (too bad :'( )

Comment: I have to send my stuff back :'-( I'd rather order 2x4gb(1066) as shown [here](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/8566DDR3S8GP/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite this thread being very old, I am answering this,
so users will have a fair idea of this model's memory compatibility.

This MacBook Pro variant will support up to 8 GB. DDR3 1066 MHz is the safest and compatible speed. Anything more than that speed is overkill. While a single 1 GB 1600 MHz may work, 2 GB's or 4 GB's with 1600 MHz will not work.

Two different speeds will default the whole memory system to the lowest speed. 1066 MHz + 1600 MHz will run at 1066 MHz - Automated Down-clocking by the system.

And the only other way to down-clock would be to use a Windows environment, edit the speed and back to Macintosh OS.

Refer this [solution](http://tylermilner.com/?p=342)

Good luck!